# Road trip in Europe: Barcelona to Budapest

Tags: trains, driving, eastern-europe, budapest

A person and I are planning a trip in which we would like to start in Barcelona and head to east, ending in Budapest.

For the moment all we know is that besides these two cities, we'd also like to visit the southern part of France, and Venice.

What's the best way to do the actual moving around part? Eurorail? Rent a car?

Comment: What’s your citizenships? Yes, this may sound like a weird question but it determines how much Interrail will be an option … ;)

Comment: This is very broad and opinion based, and as such not a good fit for sites like this (there is no clear way to decide what the correct answer for this question would be). If you have a fixed time and a fixed budget, you could find out for yourself how much a train trips costs and how long it takes, for instance, and then decide how you like that. If you can't find that out, then ask a question about how you'd find that (if there isn't one already). The main problem with rental cars is that it's one way between countries, there are already questions about that too.

Comment: If you go by train, it's not a road trip by definition!

Comment: @DavidRicherby true ;)